# Create a stream of XML document with declaration and doctype tags removed

Tags: xml, node.js, node.js-stream

Heres what Im trying to do
Goal: Pipe stream of XML document with declaration and doctype tag removed. 
Question
Part 1. Whats the best way to go about this. Should I use FS module's createReadStream and createWriteStream methods? 
Part 2. How do I remove text from one stream and pipe that into another stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fs.createReadStream` and `fs.createWriteStream` to read and write xml data respectively. Now to remove some text you need a duplex stream that is both readable and writable. In Node 0.10+ you can use the builtin [Transform Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1). Here is a simple code to use Transform stream:

```
var Transform = require('stream').Transform 
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs')

util.inherits(MyTransform, Transform);
function MyTransform(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof MyTransform))
    return new MyTransform(options);

  Transform.call(this, options);

  // init Transform
  Transform.call(this, options);
}

MyTransform.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
  //do your processing with chunk
  this.push(chunk);
  done();
};

rstream = fs.createReadStream('input.xml')
wstream = fs.createWriteStream('output.xml')
tstream = new MyTransform()

rstream
  .pipe(tstream)
  .pipe(wstream)
```